# Assign multiple values of a list

Tags: python, list

I am curious to know if there is a "pythonic" way to assign the values in a list to elements? To be clearer, I am asking for something like this:

```
myList = [3, 5, 7, 2]

a, b, c, d = something(myList)
```

So that:

```
a = 3
b = 5
c = 7
d = 2
```

I am looking for any other, better option than doing this manually:

```
a = myList[0]
b = myList[1]
c = myList[2]
d = myList[3]
```

Comment: `'assing' != 'assign'`, although that's a very amusing typo

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Simply type it out:

```
>>> a,b,c,d = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
>>> d
4
```

Python employs `assignment unpacking` when you have an `iterable` being assigned to multiple variables like above.

In `Python3.x` this has been extended, as you can also unpack to a number of variables that is less than the length of the `iterable` using the star operator:

```
>>> a,b,*c = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score 11):

Totally agree with NDevox's answer

```
a,b,c,d = [1,2,3,4]
```

I think it is also worth to mention that if you only need part of the list e.g only the second and last element from the list, you could do

```
_, a, _, b = [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 6):

`a, b, c, d = myList`
is what you want.

Basically, the function returns a tuple, which is similar to a list - because it is an iterable.

This works with all iterables btw. And you need to know the length of the iterable when using it.

Comment: This will fail with a `ValueError` in case myList doesn't exactly have items in it.

Answer (score 5):

One trick is to use the walrus operator in Python 3.8 so that you still have the my_list variable. And make it a one-line operation.

```
>>> my_list = [a:=3, b:=5, c:=7, d:=2]
>>> a
3
>>> b
5
>>> c
7
>>> d
2
>>> my_list
[3, 5, 7, 2]
```

PS: Using camelCase (myList) is not pythonic too.

What's new in Python 3.8 : https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a dictionary. This was if you have more elements in a list, you don't have to waste time hardcoding that.

```
import string
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
var = {let:num for num,let in zip(arr,string.ascii_lowercase)}
```

Now we can access variables in this dictionary like so.

```
var['a']
```