# Pulling values from lists nested in a dictionary using for loop

Tags: python-3.x

Background on what I am doing for context:

I used a scraping tool to return prices for items on various sites to compare them. The information was originally stored as nested dictionaries of the form

> {'55" 4K HDR': {'BEST BUY': 279.99, "KOHL'S": 279.99,'TARGET': 279.99},
>
> '55" 4K UHD LED': {'BEST BUY': 329.99,'COSTCO': 349.99,'TARGET': 329.99, 'WALMART': 328.0}...}

and so on. I used for loops to then reorder the nested dictionaries to only have the lowest price, but in doing so converted them to lists.

```
def sortKey(keyValue):
    g = {}
    for k, subdic in keyValue.items():
        g[k] = {}
        for subk, v in sorted(subdic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
            g[k] = [subk, v]
    return g
```

This resulted in the following output

> {'55" 4K HDR': ['BEST BUY', 279.99],
>    '55" 4K UHD LED': ['WALMART', 328.0]...}

Now I am trying to switch the format of the nested lists into a single dictionary so I can use a greedy algorithm to find all the ways I can spend a certain budget. I am hoping to get an output like

> {'55" 4K HDR': 279.99, '55" 4K UHD LED': 328.0...}

and so on. I am trying to use a similar for loop to the one I used before

```
def greedyKey(keyGreed):
    f= {}
    for g, subGreed in keyGreed.items():
        f[g] = ()
        for subg, v in subGreed:
            f = v
    return f
```

but am getting

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I know this has to do with the values of my lists, but I am confused because I thought each nested list only had 2 values

> ['WALMART', 328.0]

minimal executable example

```
import pprint

dataDict = {'55" 4K HDR': {'BEST BUY': 279.99, "KOHL'S": 279.99,'TARGET': 279.99},
'55" 4K UHD LED': {'BEST BUY': 329.99,'COSTCO': 349.99,'TARGET': 329.99, 'WALMART': 328.0}}

def sortKey(keyValue):
    g = {}
    for k, subdic in keyValue.items():
        g[k] = {}
        for subk, v in sorted(subdic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
            g[k] = [subk, v]
    return g

def greedyKey(keyGreed):
    f= {}
    for g, subGreed in keyGreed.items():
        f[g] = ()
        for subg, v in subGreed:
            f = v
    return f

masterList = sortKey(dataDict)

pprint.pprint(masterList)

greedyList = greedyKey(masterList)

pprint.pprint(greedyList)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, *executable* example? Apparently, you are showing function bodies but not the signatures, nor how they are called. Is ``keyGreed`` the ``g`` of the first code block? Did you check/print some values of ``subGreed`` to confirm they are what you thought they would be?

Comment: Sorry, `keyGreed` was the parameter for my function and I missed that copying my code in. I edited it in now. `subGreed` is giving me what I thought was the right output, it is the nested loop that is not working. If i comment out the nested loop I get _{'55" 4K HDR': (), '55" 4K UHD LED': ()...}_

Comment: I also added a minimal executable example at the end so you could copy & paste to run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31426095/5070837) answer which states:

> Python employs `assignment unpacking` when you have an `iterable` being assigned to multiple variables.

Essentially, `subg, v = subGreed` is equivalent to `subg, v = subGreed[0], subGreed[1]`, which is what I think you're looking for here.
There is no need to make `f[g]` a tuple, either.

```
def greedyKey(keyGreed):
    f = {}
    for g, subGreed in keyGreed.items():
        subg, v = subGreed
        f[g] = v
    return f
```

Comment: I appreciate the help and your explanation! However, I do not understand how the answer you linked answers my question. It says what assignment unpacking is (which I had read elsewhere but did not find particularly helpful), but the solutions given instructs the poster to simply write out and manually assign his values.

I can't do this because while I gave you a minimal executable with only 2 entries, my actual code is pulling hundreds of entries from the internet. I would not have been able to manually assign them all. That is why I wanted help building a loop, which you did.

Comment: Glad you found the code helpful. Please accept it if it solves your issue.

As for the link, I thought it would explain what I'd primarily changed in your code to make it work. I am not instructing you to manually assign the values, but trying to point out how assignment unpacking works since you were trying to iterate over `subGreed` instead.